# Need to apply IAMPass Role to specific environment

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have cloudformation template. Here we have multiple environments(dev,qa,uat) and need to use same template for all environments.
In template Under **"Action": ["iam:PassRole"]** there are 4 resources, 3 resources are belongs to qa. When am deploying code on dev and uat Env, **qa resources** are applying to dev and uat environment as well but I need to create these 3 qa resources only for qa environment. I tried some conditions but isn't working. Is there any approach for this.
Please find below template code.

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "CloudFormationRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Description": "Service role in IAM for AWS CloudFormation",
      "Properties": {
        "RoleName": {
          "Fn::Sub": "${Environment}-workflow-CloudFormationRole"
        },
        "Path": "/",
        "Policies": [
          {
            "PolicyName": "WorkerCloudFormationRolePolicy",
            "PolicyDocument": {
              "Statement": [
                {
                  "Action": [
                    "lambda:AddPermission",
                    "lambda:PutFunctionEventInvokeConfig",
                    "lambda:UpdateFunctionEventInvokeConfig"
                  ],
                  "Resource": {
                    "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:lambda:function:orderser-${Environment}-workflow-*"
                  },
                  "Effect": "Allow"
                },
                {
                  "Action": [
                    "iam:PassRole"
                  ],
                  "Resource": [
                    {"Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::role/orderser-workflow-*"},
                    {"Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::role/orderserv-qa-workflowLambdaRole1"},
                    {"Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::role/orderserv-qa-workflowLambdaRole2"},
                    {"Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::role/orderserv-qa-workflowLmbdRole3"}
                  ],
                  "Effect": "Allow"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameterize the pass role ARNs and have different set of parameter files for each environment

And, since you have multiple values, use CommaDelimitedList type parameter which can take multiple string values

Ref here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html